# Source.getLine - the line index, first line is 1

Tags: scala

Why index starts from 1 not from 0?
http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/io/Source.html

Answer (score 1):

Line numbers traditionally start at 1. Wikipedia says:

> The most common method of assigning
>   numbers to lines is to assign every
>   line a unique number, starting at 1
>   for the first line, and incrementing
>   by 1 for each successive line.

The first high level programming language (Fortran) uses 1 for the index of the first element of an array. It was the C programming language that popularised using 0 for the first index.

Answer (score 0):

Because humans normally start counting at 1. Class `Source` in Scala is a representation of a source (text) file, and it's natural to start counting with the first line as number 1.

Comment: It'd be nice if Scala had an IO library and not something that is exists only to support their compiler.  I think it's coming in 2.8.

Comment: It is not coming in 2.8, but people are now actively discussing such a library. You can cheat and use functions from the compiler, though.